# How to access SASL configure kafka from Kafka cli

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

I have a SASL PLAIN configured Kafka but can't connect to it using cli and the documentation is not clear. Below is the command I am using as of now.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9093
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

There's a section in the Kafka documentation that details the required configuration to connect to a cluster with SASL Plain: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_sasl_plain_clientconfig

It lists the following settings:

```
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
        username="alice" \
        password="alice-secret";
```

Obviously depending on the SSL configuration, you may need to add a few extra settings, see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_configclients

Put all these settings in a file, then you can specify this file using the `--command-config` when using `kafka-topics.sh`. For example:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --command-config /path/to/file.properties
```